# Streaming a webcam video to a web-page

Tags: software-recommendation, webcam, webserver, streaming

I need software which is able to capture images from a webcam and stream them to a web-page.

I already tried a webcam-server, but it uses java applet on the client side for retrieving pictures, which is not supported on my client device (Android tablet).

An alternative may be be something that captures images from a webcam and writes them to the same file, constantly rewriting it. In that case, my java-script on the client side can just use this file to constantly refresh an image.

Any ideas and suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah you're on the right path. Deal with standard images and update it with javascript.

You should [have a look at `webcam`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/man1/webcam.1.html) which is a little command line app that just snaps away and can upload over FTP. If you don't have an FTP server (eg only SSH) you could mount that and have it upload that way.

One note about refreshing the images: stick `'?var=' + (new Date).getTime()` on the end of the image URL each time you fetch it. This just forces the browser not to use a cached copy. And make sure you don't set the refresh interval too aggressive.

Comment: Thank you for your respond. Is there any way to tell a webcam software to upload image to the local directory, not ftp server?

Comment: I found. It can be easily configured to save image to the local directory.

Comment: I used the webcam utility and it completely solved my problem after some editing of its configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

To share webcam and mic, you can always just create a [jitsi.org](https://jitsi.org/) meeting (ie, [WebRTC](https://webrtc.org/); or with any alternative). After letting your browser to access those devices, anyone having the generated meeting link could access.

To remotely assist to other users check [this related answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1198424/349837).

To record video check for [motion](https://motion-project.github.io/) or [Shinobi](https://askubuntu.com/a/878069/349837).