# Recommend FOSS Webcam Sharing Software

Tags: 14.04, webcam

This question feels lousy to ask but... I am just having the hardest time finding software that can let me share what my USB webcam sees with my co-workers on a LAN.

Cheese is popular but it seems to require me to manually take and post a picture.  I want them to see whatever it's pointed at whenever they look, even if I am home sick that day.

Running Ubuntu 14.04 and Gnome desktop

Comment: Do you want to stream from your webcam?

Comment: See https://gist.github.com/endolith/2052778 and http://xmodulo.com/live-stream-video-webcam-linux.html

Comment: @user68186 I don't think full-motion streaming is essential but the current still image when a user requests one is good.

Comment: the VLC solution looks promising, I am going to try that now

Comment: The software motion is very flexible. I think one can configure it to take snap shots at fixed intervals and send it to some server. However, I have not used motion in a while, and so I am not inclined to write a full answer.Also see http://askubuntu.com/questions/98035/streaming-a-webcam-video-to-the-web-page-in-ubuntu

Comment: I wrote a related answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1389650/349837)

Answer (score 0):

Another option is zoneminder. You will need to add the zoneminder repository:

```
apt-get install software-properties-common python-software-properties
add-apt-repository ppa:iconnor/zoneminder
apt-get update
```

You will also need apache2 ubuntu-restricted-extras libav-tools x264:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2 ubuntu-restricted-extras libav-tools x264
```

[Click here for more instructions on how to set up mysql and php.](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu)

Then,

[Follow the instructions here and be patient with the setup. You will probably have to mess around with the individual camera settings before it will work.](http://www.zoneminder.com/wiki/index.php/Ubuntu_Server_14.04_64-bit_with_Zoneminder_1.28.0_the_easy_way)

You can set up passwords for security so that not just anybody can see the camera. They will have access to the server through any web browser.

The zoneminder server will auto start when you start ubuntu and it runs in the background.

After you get it set up, you can take note of the URL (using the static ip of your computer) for the camera feed to give to users to access the camera if you like or you can inspect the html to get the feed URL to set up a minimal page of your own on your apache server accessible on the local network.

[www.zoneminder.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Documentation](http://www.zoneminder.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Documentation)

[www.zoneminder.com/wiki/index.php/Ubuntu_Server_14.04_64-bit_with_Zoneminder_1.28.0_the_easy_way](http://www.zoneminder.com/wiki/index.php/Ubuntu_Server_14.04_64-bit_with_Zoneminder_1.28.0_the_easy_way)

[www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu)