# How do I record audio and video to a file from my webcam using ffmpeg?

Tags: sound, video, webcam, ffmpeg

[This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33665/use-webcam-to-record-including-movement-detection) says to use /dev/dsp as the audio input.  But I don't have a /dev/dsp  I can find my webcam's mic in /dev/snd as /dev/snd/by-id/usb-Dynex_Dynex_1.3MP_Webcam-02

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `/dev/dsp` device comes from the old [Open Sound System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Sound_System) drivers, which are deprecated these days.  The devices you've listed support the newer [ALSA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Linux_Sound_Architecture) API, so can't be used with ffmpeg's `oss` decoder.

Instead follow the instructions in the other question, but modify the command to:

```
ffmpeg -f alsa -i $ALSA_DEVICE_NAME ...
```

Where `$ALSA_DEVICE_NAME` is the device name displayed by `arecord -L` that corresponds to your webcam.  It will likely list a few options for the webcam, but picking the one starting with `hw:` or `plughw:` should be fine.

Comment: Thank you! You're exactly correct. For the record (since good ffmpeg recipes are nice to stumble across), here's me recording a ten second video-audio clip from my webcam: ffmpeg -f alsa -i "plughw:CARD=Webcam,DEV=0" -f video4linux2 -vcodec mjpeg -s 640x480 -i "/dev/video0" -y -t 10 -sameq "/tmp/test.mp4"