# WEBCAM software with Motion Detection help with MOTION

Tags: webcam

I am searching for some Ubuntu software for using webcam.  It needs to be able to record video with motion detection with the option of saving it to disk. I have tried ZoneMinder and found it way too complex to use. I am looking for something simple, preferably something with a GUI. Everyone keeps mentioning '[Motion](https://motion-project.github.io/motion_guide.html)' however It seems VERY complicated.

If Motion is the best way to go, could someone please take the time to instruct me on how to set it up to capture video?

I have read [THIS](http://www.maketecheasier.com/setup-motion-detection-webcam-ubuntu/) tutorial on setting it up, but there is no mention of capturing video files.  I also have read this [FFMPG](http://www.lavrsen.dk/foswiki/bin/view/Motion/MpegFilmsFFmpeg) article, but have no clue how to set it up  (I do have it installed).

I am running UBUNTU 12.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for a simple program to do motion detection, I would choose a script using [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/) like [this one](https://github.com/RobinDavid/Motion-detection-OpenCV).

Or just download the first [script](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RobinDavid/Motion-detection-OpenCV/master/MotionDetector.py) and install `python-opencv`:

```
sudo apt-get install python-opencv
```

To run the script, just type in a terminal:

```
python ./MotionDetector.py
```

You will need Python 2 installed.

Comment: Ok so i see it launching some app called RES which seems to be doing something. It says RECORDING, but where do the files go?

Comment: Ok I found the folder which is just the USER folder.  THank you!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it was too complicated back in 2014. Now is pretty simple:

1. Install it, `sudo apt install motion`
2. Run `sudo sh -c "mkdir /var/log/motion && chown motion /var/log/motion"` and restart motion service (always after any config change). This [seems a bug](https://github.com/Motion-Project/motion/issues/1697).
3. By default all the [Matroska](https://matroska.org/) videos (mkv, `movie_codec`) will be on `/var/lib/motion/`.
4. On `/etc/motion/motion.conf` you might be interested in tweaking things like `event_gap`, `movie_filename` or `movie_max_time`.

You can also remove the old files with a cron job, merge videos with [mencoder](https://mplayerhq.hu/), or set areas with a PGM file on [`mask_file`](https://motion-project.github.io/motion_config.html#mask_file).

More info on [this related](https://askubuntu.com/a/33690/349837) answer.